# Automatically Deleting specific Elements in Mathematica Tables

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, nested-lists

I have a question which can be divided into two subquestions.
I have created a table the code of which is given below.

Problem 1.

```
xstep = 1;
xmaximum = 6;
numberofxnodes = 6;
numberofynodes = 3;
numberofzlayers = 3;
maximumgridnodes = numberofxnodes*numberofynodes
mnodes = numberofxnodes*numberofynodes*numberofzlayers;
orginaltable = 
   Table[{i, 
          node2 = i + xstep, node3 = node2 + xmaximum,
          node4 = node3 - xstep,node5 = i + maximumgridnodes,
          node6 = node5 + xstep,node7 = node6 + xmaximum,
          node8 = node7 - xstep}, 
        {i, 1, mnodes}]
```

If I run this I will get my original table. Basically I want to remove the sixth element and multiples of the sixth element from my original table. I am able to do this by using this code below.

```
 modifiedtable = Drop[orginaltable, {6, mnodes, 6}]
```

Now I get the modified table where every sixth element and multiples of sixth element of my original table is removed. This solves my Problem 1.

Now my Problem 2:

** MAJOR EDITED VERSION**:(ALL THE CODES GIVEN ABOVE IS CORRECT)

Thanks a lot for the answers, but I wanted something else and I made a mistake
while explaining it initially so I'm making another try.

Below is my modified table: I want the elements in between
 "/** and **/"  deleted and remaining there.

> {{1, 2, 8, 7, 19, 20, 26, 25}, {2, 3, 9, 8, 20, 21, 27, 26}, {3, 4,10, 9, 21, 22, 28, 27}, {4, 5, 11, 10, 22, 23, 29, 28}, {5, 6, 12, 11, 23, 24, 30, 29}, {7, 8, 14, 13, 25, 26, 32, 31}, {8, 9, 15, 14, 26, 27, 33, 32}, {9, 10, 16, 15, 27, 28, 34, 33}, {10, 11, 17, 16, 28, 29, 35, 34}, {11, 12, 18, 17, 29, 30, 36, 35}, /**{13, 14, 20, 19, 31, 32, 38, 37}, {14, 15, 21, 20, 32, 33, 39, 38}, {15, 16, 22, 21,  33, 34, 40, 39}, {16, 17, 23, 22, 34, 35, 41, 40}, {17, 18, 24, 23, 35, 36, 42, 41},**/ {19, 20, 26, 25, 37, 38, 44, 43}, {20, 21, 27, 26, 38, 39, 45, 44}, {21, 22, 28, 27, 39, 40, 46, 45}, {22, 23, 29, 28, 40, 41, 47, 46}, {23, 24, 30, 29, 41, 42, 48, 47}, {25, 26, 32, 31,43, 44, 50, 49}, {26, 27, 33, 32, 44, 45, 51, 50}, {27, 28, 34, 33, 45, 46, 52, 51}, {28, 29, 35, 34, 46, 47, 53, 52}, {29, 30, 36, 35, 47, 48, 54, 53}, /**{31, 32, 38, 37, 49, 50, 56, 55}, {32, 33, 39, 38,50, 51, 57, 56}, {33, 34, 40, 39, 51, 52, 58, 57}, {34, 35, 41, 40, 52, 53, 59, 58}, {35, 36, 42, 41, 53, 54, 60, 59},**/ {37, 38, 44, 43,55, 56, 62, 61}, {38, 39, 45, 44, 56, 57, 63, 62}, {39, 40, 46, 45, 57, 58, 64, 63}, {40, 41, 47, 46, 58, 59, 65, 64}, {41, 42, 48, 47,59, 60, 66, 65}, {43, 44, 50, 49, 61, 62, 68, 67}, {44, 45, 51, 50, 62, 63, 69, 68}, {45, 46, 52, 51, 63, 64, 70, 69}, {46, 47, 53, 52, 64, 65, 71, 70}, {47, 48, 54, 53, 65, 66, 72, 71}, /**{49, 50, 56, 55, 67, 68, 74, 73}, {50, 51, 57, 56, 68, 69, 75, 74},{51,52, 58, 57, 69, 70, 76, 75}, {52, 53, 59, 58, 70, 71, 77, 76}, {53, 54, 60, 59, 71, 72, 78, 77}}**/

Now, if you observe, I wanted the first ten elements
 (1st to 10th element of `modifiedtable`)  to be there in my final table 
 ( `DoubleModifiedTable` ). the the next five (11th to 15th elements of `modifiedtable`) deleted.
Then the next ten elements ( 16th to 25th elements of `modifiedtable`) 
to be present in my final table ( `DoubleModifiedTable` ) 
then the next five deleted (26th to 30th elements of `modifiedtable`) and so on for the whole table.

Let say we solve this problem and we name the final table `DoubleModifiedTable`.

I am basically  interested in getting the `DoubleModifiedTable`. I decided to subdivide the problem as it easy to explain.

I want this to happen automatically through the table since as this is just an example table but in reality I have huge table. If I can understand how I can solve this problem for this table, then I can solve it for my large table too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps simpler:

```
DoubleModifiedTable = 
  Module[{copy  = modifiedtable},
  copy[[Flatten[# + Range[5] & /@ Range[10, Length[copy], 10]]]] = Sequence[];
  copy]
```

**EDIT**

Even simpler:

```
DoubleModifiedTable =
   Delete[modifiedtable,
     Transpose[{Flatten[# + Range[5] & /@ Range[10, Length[modifiedtable], 10]]}]]
```

**EDIT 2**

Per OP's request: one only has to change a single number (10 to 15) in any of my solutions to get the answer to a modified problem:

```
DoubleModifiedTable =
  Delete[modifiedtable,
    Transpose[{Flatten[# + Range[5] & /@ Range[10, Length[modifiedtable], 15]]}]]
```

Comment: +1 that's indeed simpler than mine. Don't know what I was thinking there.

Comment: @Leonid Thanks for the answer but just have a look once more since I have edited my question quite a lot

Comment: @Proj_UK  Please see my latest edit - you only had to change a single number in any of my solutions for your second formulation.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to do something like

```
DoubleModifiedTable = With[{n = 10, m = 5},
  Flatten[{{modifiedtable[[;; m]]}, 
    Partition[modifiedtable, n - m, n, {n - m + 1, 1}, {}]}, 2]]
```

**Edit**

The edited version of Problem 2 is actually slightly simpler to solve than the original version. You could for example do something like

```
DoubleModifiedTable = 
 With[{n = 10, m = 5}, Flatten[Partition[modifiedtable, n, n + m, 1, {}], 1]]
```

**Edit 2**

What my second version does is to split the original list `modifiedtable` into sublists using `Partition` and then to flatten these sublists to form the final list. If you look at the [Documentation for Partition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html?q=Partition&lang=en) you can see that I'm using the 6th form of `Partition` which means that the length of the sublists is `n` and the offset (the distance be is `n+m`. The gap between the sublists is therefore `n+m-n==m`.

The next argument, `1`, is actually equivalent to `{1,1}` which tells Mathematica that the first element of `modifiedtable` should appear at position 1 in the first sublist and the last element of `modifiedtable` should appear on or after position 1 of the last sublist.

The last argument, `{}` is to indicate that no padding should be used for sublists with length `<=n`.

In summary, if you want to delete the first 10 elements and keep the next 5 you want sublists of length `n=5` with gap `m=10`. Since you want the first sublist to start with the `(m+1)`-th element of `modifiedtable`, you could replace the fourth argument in `Partition` with something of the form `{k,1}` for some value of `k` but it's probably easier to just drop the first `m` elements of `modifiedtable` beforehand, i.e.

```
DoubleModifiedTable = 
 With[{n = 5, m = 10}, 
  Flatten[Partition[Drop[modifiedtable, m], n, n + m, 1, {}], 1]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer...But I have edited my question it would be good if you could have a look one more time

Comment: Thaks for the answer I have two more question in fact one related to this itself and another one but both are almost similar.

Comment: Even through I modified you code and used it ,I haven't actually understood it. Now I want the first ten elements deleted and next five remaining and so on...How can I modify this code.If you could help me with the code and a bit of explanation..it will help me in the long run.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
DoubleModifiedTable=
modifiedtable[[
  Complement[
   Range[Length[modifiedtable]],
   Flatten@Table[10 i + j, {i, Floor[Length[modifiedtable]/10]}, {j, 5}]
  ]
]]
```

or, slightly shorter

```
DoubleModifiedTable=
#[[
    Complement[
       Range[Length[#]],
       Flatten@Table[10 i + j, {i, Floor[Length[#]/10]}, {j, 5}]
     ]
 ]] & @ modifiedtable
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer...But I have edited my question it would be good if you could have a look one more time